# What does the GNU makefile flag "-m" mean, and how does it operate in the line "Obj -m += simple.o"?

Tags: gnu-make, gnu, flags

I'm am taking a course in operating systems, and we were asked to explain the syntax of a given makefile.  However, I'm having trouble understanding the contents:

```
Obj -m += simple.o

all:
        make -C/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The main part I don't understand is the first line.  From what I know "Obj" is a variable name "-m" is a flag "+=" is the concatenate operator "simple.o" is the object file.  Even though I know the parts I don't know what this line does.  I have searched extensively, but I can't find any explanation of "-m" flag.  It showed up in only one list explaining that the compiler knows to ignore it, see here https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html. Can someone explain what this line means and does?

Comment: You have mistyped your first line.  That's a syntax error in make which is maybe why you don't understand it.  I'm sure in your given makefile it actually says `Obj-m += simple.o` (there is no space between `Obj` and `-m`).

Comment: In any event, the `-m` option is ignored, as per the page you link to; and if it wasn't, this would not be how you enable it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I'm used to seeing flags denoted by -(flag) and I assumed -m must have been a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [Linux kbuild makefile](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/) for an out-of-kernel-tree module. As @MadScientist has pointed out your first line should read

```
obj-m += simple.o
```

In Linux kbuild context this means "compile and link simple.c to the module". The goal `all` (default goal) will build the module against the kernel version you are currently running on.

**NOTE:** you'll need to install the kernel development headers in order for the module build to succeed.

**EDIT:** inside the Linux kernel tree you'll also find the notation `obj-y += X` which means "compile and link X into the kernel when this kernel config has been enabled".

Comment: Thank you for the link and explaining this line, it really helped!  I compiled the makefile and added this to the kernel successfully.  As far as my understanding, am i correct to assume obj-m is a module I have created and obj-y is a module that was part of the kernel already?  Therefore, if I used obj-y this would mean that I'm modifying an existing module, and not creating a new one?

Comment: You can't use `obj-y` outside the kernel source tree, as the kernel is already linked. I forgot to mention that the actual usage is usually `obj-$(CONFIG_XYZ)`, i.e. when `CONFIG_XYZ` is set to `y` that object will be added to kernel. If it is set to `m` that object will go to a kernel module. If it is set to `n` the object is not built.

Comment: I did more research based on your comments, and I think I understand the difference now.  "obj-y" means the program will be added to the kernel's config directory as a static program, therefore it will run every time the kernel boots, as a part of it.  "obj-m" means the program will be created as a kernel module and called (added/removed) dynamically as needed.  Is this right?

Comment: `obj-y` objects will be linked directly into the kernel binary, i.e. `vmlinux`. But otherwise I think you got it.